# Is dynamic javascript added synchronously or not?

Tags: javascript

Also, when is the code loaded, on setting the `.src` attribute or on appending the element.  To illustrate:

```
var test = document.createElement('script');
test.src = 'some_path'; 
// is code loaded here?
document.head.appendChild(test);
// or here?
...
// or is it an asynch operation?
```

Comment: Did you try it out by placing some `console.log` calls on strategically good locations? :)

Comment: `element.onload = callback; element.async = true;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating a script element dynamically, **the source file will not be loaded or executed before the element has been inserted into the document**. Loading of a script is **asynchronous**. This means your code does the following:

1. Create the script element
2. Assign a source attribute
3. Place the element into the document
4. Start loading the source file asynchronously
5. When loaded, execute the script

**Edit:** Thanks for pointing out that setting the *async* property does not have any effect on the loading behaviour of scripts. I never actually used it and assumed it would work, but it apparently does not. I removed the part claiming it would. [I made an example to show this](http://jsbin.com/ivasobo/2/edit?js,console).

Answer (score 1):

Javascript runs top to bottom unless it's a function, an asynchronous call to a server, or in a closure that waits for some event (ie: `window.load()`)

Your code is as follows:

```
var test = document.createElement('script');
//declare variable test to create script element
test.src = 'some_path'; 
//define element with src attribute 'some_path'

document.head.appendChild(test);
//place script element in head block
```

Though I would recommend creating dynamic script blocks server-side to avoid complications due to exceptions and high-load/timeout possibilities.

You can insert breakpoints in Firebug and Chrome Dev tools to step through your scripts and see what is happening too.  More Info: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging